# [Apache Beam/ Dataflow]: Maintain states outside of the Dataflow Job

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

We have a problem where we need to maintain states for a long period of time (weeks) across windows. Widening a window is not feasible and in order to guarantee that state is maintained throughout failure scenarios (topology restarts).

Example use case:
I want to see if an callback for a given impression have been observed within past 5 weeks period as I am processing the events. Based on the state check, I may or may not process this event as part of the aggregation. The most important requirement here is that I need to keep the state across multiple windows and keeping a long window and triggering is not feasible as we are interested in lookback of up to 5 weeks.

I am leaning toward using external state rather than using stateful DoFns which is keyed per window. For example, using KV store to lookup the state from the Dataflow job as needed. There is some overhead involved in this approach as we need to maintain external storages and this state need to be atomic with respect to different life cycle scenarios. For example if a state is updated but job dies, how do we rollback the state?

- What is the best way to approach this type of problems?
- Is there a    publication  such as a white paper that discusses this
  type of    problems?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what is your process and problem. So I can investigate further a feasible solution?

Comment: @AlexandreMoraes I included some example in the question.

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?